# Use .json extension to force JSON output from an Express.js endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, express

Is it possible to set up endpoints in Express.js in such a way that the user can signal they'd like only JSON output by appending .json to the URL?

For example, if I have the endpoint `example.com/data/:data_id`, is there a function `someFunction` such that if I hit the endpoint `example.json/data/:data_id` with the following code I would be able to get JSON output out?

```
router.get('/data/:data_id', function(req, res, next) {
    var extension = req.someFunction();
    if (extension === 'json') {
        res.json({...});
    } else {
        res.render('view', {...});
    };
});
```

I know there is probably a way to do that with content headers, but I've seen it [recommended](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#json-responses) that content type be specified by an extension so that APIs can be browsed by a browser.

Comment: Could probably add middleware that strips the .json off the url so that the routing will work as if it wasn't there, and then set a value on `req` so that the routes know what format to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just add a format parameter in the query url

```js
router.get('/data/:data_id', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.format && req.query.format === 'json') {
        res.json({...});
    } else {
        res.render('view', {...});
    };
});
```

something like this !